# How to connect to IBM MQ Manager with HA configuration?

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am writing a C# client that connects to IBM Websphere MQ Manager using amqmdnet.dll using the following construct:

```
_myQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, properties);
```

In the properties Hashtable I am setting hostname, channel and queuemanager. Now, how can I have auto reconnect functionality in my client application? We have IBM MQ multi-instance queue manager HA configuration.

Basically, I have four end points to which I have to fall back in case of connection failure from my client?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111270_.htm):

> You can supply a list of hostnames and ports as an argument to the
>   constructor MQQueueManager (String queueManagerName, Hashtable
>   properties) using CONNECTION_NAME_PROPERTY.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> ConnectionName = "fred.mq.com(2344),nick.mq.com(3746),tom.mq.com(4288)";
> Hashtable Properties-new Hashtable();
> properties.Add(MQC.CONNECTION_NAME_PROPERTY,ConnectionName);
> MQQueueManager qmgr=new MQQueue Manager("qmgrname",properties);
> ```
>
> When a connection attempt is made, the connection name list is
>   processed in order. If the connection attempt to the first host name
>   and port fails, then connection to the second pair of attributes is
>   attempted. The client repeats this process until either a successful
>   connection is made or the list is exhausted. If the list is exhausted,
>   an appropriate reason code and completion code is returned to the
>   client application.

Be sure to also follow the advice in [Automatic client reconnection in .NET](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029650_.htm) to make sure the option is correctly specified with respect to managed/unmanaged mode.

Comment: Thanks Rob. This is exactly what I was looking for. I also found the same in the sample: SimpleClientAutoReconnectGet. For other who might be interested in, IBM samples can found in the install directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Tools\dotnet\samples\cs

Comment: Is their any link for Java for the same set up?